# Shell script to parse a list of emails and check if their mx record is on a file

Tags: linux, email, dns, sh

I needed a shell script that parses a txt with emails and does a simple dig:
Grab the domain from the email:

```
echo someone@domain.com | awk -F "@" '{print $2}'
```

and the dig

```
dig @127.0.0.1 +short mx $domain | sed 's/\.$//'
```

on an email and i needed to check if any of the MX records are present in a file.
This file contains the big email service providers mx records for example:

```
aa-com.mail.protection.outlook.com
alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
```

if any of those mx matches i want to put these emails on another file so that i have private domains on one side and ESP's on the other file.

any help is appreciated.
thanks in advance

Comment: And what did you try? "I needed a shell script" is not how this forum is supposed to work, it is not a "please code on my behalf", it should be related to specific questions and errors you have in YOUR code and then help you fix it. So what is your code besides two lines shown?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#/bin/bash
cat emails.txt |while read email
do 
    domain=$(echo $email | awk -F "@" '{print $2}')
    dig +short mx $domain |awk '{print $2}'|sed 's/\.$//' |while read mx
    do
        if grep -qs $mx mx_records.txt
        then
            echo $email
            break
        fi
    done
done
```

There is a number at the beginning of the dig output,

```
# dig mx apple.com  +short
10 rn-mailsvcp-ppex-lapp34.apple.com.
10 rn-mailsvcp-ppex-lapp45.apple.com.
10 rn-mailsvcp-ppex-lapp44.apple.com.
```

so i filtered them with `awk '{print $2}'`.

This script prints the matched emails as a standerd output, you can redirect the output to another file.